# MATLAB: recall previous command and ADD it to what I typed (similar to bash)

Tags: command-line, bash, matlab

On the MATLAB commandline, I can recall the previous command with the UP arrow. However, if I already have typed something and *then* hit UP arrow, only commands beginning with what I already typed will show up.
This is mostly useful, and very annoying at the same time.
Often what I want is this:

```
>> longVariable

longVariable =

     1     2
     3     4
```

and immediately afterwards I want to type something like

```
size(<thatLastThing>)
```

which in `bash` I can just do by typing ALT+. (beautiful).
I can't get that behavior in MATLAB though... unless you can help me out?

PS: I am aware that I could just hit UP arrow, POS1, "size(" etc - it's what I am doing now, but it is very counter intuitive to me.

PPS: Today I discovered that my desired behavior is correctly implemented in `octave` - which is very nice for *octave*, but I'd really love to have this in *Matlab*...

Answer (score 0):

Basically, `ans` is a "variable" that Matlab creates when you type any command that returns output without specifying output argument. Read more [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ans.html)

So if you write something like this:

```
[1 2 3];
ans
```

the result will be

```
[1 2 3]
```

and if you write

```
size(ans)
```

you'll get

```
[1 3]
```

hope it helps!

Comment: I tried that before, but in my above example, `size(ans)` gives me `1 2` when it should be `2 2`.